# Quarto - How to embed files in outputted word documents programmatically?

Tags: r-markdown, quarto

My quarto document uses knitr as the backend. I have the output set to create a word document. I would like the outputted word document to also contain an embedded object that is the file used to create the word document itself.

So `create_word.qmd` will create `output_word_file.docx`. I would like there to be an embedded object in the `output_word_file.docx` file that is a copy of `create_word.qmd`. Is this possible programmatically? Or do I need to manually do this part?

If it's only possible using the .Rmd file type then I can make that work.

Comment: The file or the code?

Comment: The actual file.